# Nonlinear system solver could not converge

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

[image: there is outlet mass flow rate changing when the valve opens]

I am using the default dassl integrator. In my model a volume is controlled using Booleans to open or close 4 valves (2 work together). After the state of the boolean changes (from 1 to zero) with milliseconds I receive this error message:

[image: am having this error msg]

Is there any way to find out more about what is causing the problem?

```
model CONTROLLER
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput V_LT_min;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput V_LT_max;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput V_LT_lev;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.BooleanOutput open1(start=true);
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.BooleanOutput open2(start=false);
equation 
  when (V_LT_lev <= V_LT_max) then
    open1 = true;
  elsewhen (V_LT_lev < V_LT_min) then
    open1 = false;
  end when;
  open2 = not open1;
end CONTROLLER;

model EV_LT
  package SI = Modelica.SIunits;
  package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.WaterIF97_ph;
  Thermofluid_connector port_e;
  Thermofluid_connector port_s;
  parameter Real Kv=3.79;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.BooleanInput open;
  Real dbM;
  Real delta_p;
equation 
  //dbM=port_e.dbM;
  delta_p = (port_e.p - port_s.p)/10^5;
  if (delta_p >= 10^(-5)) then
    dbM = Kv*sqrt(delta_p)*1000/3600;
  else
    dbM = 0;
  end if;
  port_e.dbM = if open then dbM else 0;
  port_e.dbM + port_s.dbM = 0;
  port_s.dbH = port_s.dbM*port_s.h;
  port_e.h = port_s.h;
end EV_LT;

connector Thermofluid_connector
  package SI = Modelica.SIunits;
  SI.AbsolutePressure p;
  flow SI.MassFlowRate dbM;
  SI.SpecificEnthalpy h;
  flow SI.EnthalpyFlowRate dbH;
equation 

end Thermofluid_connector;
```

Comment: Do you directly influence the derivative of a state with the valve? If you set it to zero that could be the problem. You might have created a system with dynamic differential index that needs to be modeled differently. 

It would help if you could provide example code.

Comment: i added the controller model that am using

Comment: the equation for the mass flow rate of the valve  is :port_e.dM=if open dbM else 0;                                       where dbM=Kv*delta_p**rho

Comment: It would help if you could provide the example model in TEXT form, so that others can just copy and paste it to their tool and run it. In the picture you have provided, you are using <= (LESS than) in BOTH conditions. Is this intended?

Comment: i added the valve model and the controller model that control the state on/off of the valve,thanks @matth

Comment: It still looks like we are missing something, e.g. `Thermofluid_connector` does not seem to be defined. Are you using an additional library?

Also the operators < and <= for real variables are equal in openmodelica. We do not check continuous variables for equality because that will be wrong due to numerical errors anyway, the only thing we check are the actual zero crossings. If you influence those continuous variables to be discrete at given points and want an actual equality check for that, you could use `Modelica.Math.isEqual` from the MSL. A minimal error tolerance can be provided.

Comment: A i just saw what @matth actually meant. You check both times for upper bounds, which indeed does not seem right.

Comment: the main model work fine for 9 seconds and it stops there , i cant provide all models in the main model cause its condfidentail sorry, but i can  say that the valvels aare to control the volume level i a tank ,and the tank is 3/100 full ,the input valve turns off and the output valve turns ON ,and in tis moment i have the error msg

Comment: and am not using am additional library

Answer (score 0):

I looked a little bit deeper into this model and i don't know why any of this works on your system actually. I tried to simulate the model `EV_LT` and ran into a structural singularity which is quite obvious looking at the system.

You define the equation `port_e.dbM + port_s.dbM = 0.0;` and because neither `port_e` nor `port_s` are connected to anything the equations `port_e.dbM = 0.0` and `port_s.dbM = 0.0` are generated (Flow is set to zero for unconnected connectors). These are three equations with only 2 unknowns -> structural singularity. The compiler actually tries to resolve this by differentiating these (index reduction), but as you might imagine that does not yield any additional information whatsoever.

Are you sure you simulated the exact model stated above?

If you are talking about the simulation of only the controller, that does work but is pretty unexciting since it does not depend on time at all.

EDIT: Can you provide the omc version you are working with? I tested it with 1.14 and 1.16~dev. Maybe you have an older version and should upgrade.